# How to import contacts from phonebook to our application

Tags: android

I am developing the android application ,when ever user clicks on the button it should show all contacts from the phone book with in a table.How can i achieve it,any one can help me.thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

If you query the [ContactsContract.Contacts](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html) content provider you will get cursor with the list of contacts.

Answer (score 3):

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Use this piece of code under the button.setOnClick function you'll get the display of all the contacts in the phone book

Comment: where is delegate method of this intent?

Answer (score 2):

give you some codes:

```
     ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
    //get name
    int nameFiledColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME);
    String contact = cursor.getString(nameFiledColumnIndex);

    String[] PHONES_PROJECTION = new String[] { "_id","display_name","data1","data3"};//
    String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup._ID));
    Cursor phone = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, PHONES_PROJECTION,
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=" + contactId, null, null);
    //name type ..
    while(phone.moveToNext()) {
        int i = phone.getInt(0);
        String str = phone.getString(1);
        str = phone.getString(2);
        str = phone.getString(3);
        }
        phone.close();
        //addr
        Cursor addrCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_URI ,
     new String[]{"_id","data1","data2","data3"}, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=" + contactId , null, null);
        while(addrCur.moveToNext()) {
        int i = addrCur.getInt(0);
        String str = addrCur.getString(1);
        str = addrCur.getString(2);
        str = addrCur.getString(3);
        }
        addrCur.close();

        //email
        Cursor emailCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI ,
     new String[]{"_id","data1","data2","data3"}, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=" + contactId , null, null);
        while(emailCur.moveToNext()) {
        int i = emailCur.getInt(0);
        String str = emailCur.getString(1);
        str = emailCur.getString(2);
        str = emailCur.getString(3);
        }
        emailCur.close();

    }
    cursor.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code inside the button.setonclicklistener.

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);