# How to pick the contact name and store it in our application

Tags: android

I want to pick a contact name from contact list and then want to store this contact name in my app in list view.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

see this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866769/how-to-call-android-contacts-list)

Dont forget to add permission to your android manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

For further details see [Using the Contacts API](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/contacts.html)
 and android's [Contact manager example app](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ContactManager/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

check following links:

[How to call Android contacts list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866769/how-to-call-android-contacts-list)

[How to get contacts from native phonebook in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253029/how-to-get-contacts-from-native-phonebook-in-android)

[How to obtain all details of a contact in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205246/how-to-obtain-all-details-of-a-contact-in-android)

[How to get the first name and last name from Android contacts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301064/how-to-get-the-firstname-and-lastname-from-android-contacts)

[How to import contacts from phonebook to our application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662473/how-to-import-contacts-from-phonebook-to-our-application)

[Android contacts extraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588378/android-contacts-extraction)

[How to get all android contacts but without those which are on SIM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338563/how-to-get-all-android-contacts-but-without-those-which-are-on-sim)