# How to access SMS and contacts data?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

is content providers the only way to read/write private data such SMS and contacts? I first try the easy and lazy way (copy sms and contacts SQLite databases files) but I faced some permission issues. I'm asking because I'm trying to backup and restore SMS and contacts and that would be a lot of work accessing data field one by one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Getting Contacts:

[How to call Android contacts list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866769/how-to-call-android-contacts-list)

[How to get contacts from native phonebook in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253029/how-to-get-contacts-from-native-phonebook-in-android)

[How to obtain all details of a contact in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205246/how-to-obtain-all-details-of-a-contact-in-android)

[How to get the first name and last name from Android contacts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301064/how-to-get-the-firstname-and-lastname-from-android-contacts)

[How to import contacts from phonebook to our application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662473/how-to-import-contacts-from-phonebook-to-our-application)

[Android contacts extraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588378/android-contacts-extraction)

[How to get all android contacts but without those which are on SIM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338563/how-to-get-all-android-contacts-but-without-those-which-are-on-sim)

and for sms:

```
Uri mSmsinboxQueryUri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        Cursor cursor1 = getContentResolver().query(mSmsinboxQueryUri,
                    new String[] { "_id", "thread_id", "address", "person", "date",
                                    "body", "type" }, null, null, null);
        startManagingCursor(cursor1);
        String[] columns = new String[] { "address", "person", "date", "body","type" };
        if (cursor1.getCount() > 0) {
            String count = Integer.toString(cursor1.getCount());
            Log.e("Count",count);
            while (cursor1.moveToNext()){
                String address = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[0]));
                String name = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[1]));
                String date = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[2]));
                String msg = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[3]));
                String type = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[4]));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the contact

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null);
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> contactData=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
         while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
             try{
             String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID)); 
             String name=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
             String hasPhone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)); 
             if (Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                 Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ contactId, null, null);
                 while (phones.moveToNext()) { 
                     String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                     HashMap<String,String> map=new HashMap<String,String>();
                     map.put("name", name);
                     map.put("number", phoneNumber);
                     contactData.add(map);
                 } 
                 phones.close(); 
             }
         }catch(Exception e){}
         }
```

To read the sms from the inbox

```
Uri mSmsinboxQueryUri = Uri.parse("content://sms");
Cursor cursor1 = getContentResolver().query(
        mSmsinboxQueryUri,
        new String[] { "_id", "thread_id", "address", "person", "date",
                "body", "type" }, null, null, null);
startManagingCursor(cursor1);
String[] columns = new String[] { "address", "person", "date", "body",
        "type" };
if (cursor1.getCount() > 0) {
    String count = Integer.toString(cursor1.getCount());
    Log.e("Count",count);
    while (cursor1.moveToNext()) {
        out.write("<message>");
        String address = cursor1.getString(cursor1
                .getColumnIndex(columns[0]));
        String name = cursor1.getString(cursor1
                .getColumnIndex(columns[1]));
        String date = cursor1.getString(cursor1
                .getColumnIndex(columns[2]));
        String msg = cursor1.getString(cursor1
                .getColumnIndex(columns[3]));
        String type = cursor1.getString(cursor1
                .getColumnIndex(columns[4]));
```

}
 }