# Display a list of contacts in listview when typing a phone number OR name in my edittext

Tags: android, search, android-softkeyboard

Apart from this related question I can't find anything online about what I'm looking for:
[Display a list of contact as I type name OR phone number in the input box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267235/display-a-list-of-contact-as-i-type-name-or-phone-number-in-the-input-box).

Basically, if the user types for example the keys 1,2,3 in the searchview, 123 is shown in the searchview, and all contacts with phone numbers including 123 are shown in the listview. I've got this far.

But I also want to see contacts like, 'CEG', or 'BEG' in the listview. Any pointers on where I can even start to learn more about this would be  help.

I need to display the phone input. I have this set in my XML:
[image]

The salient parts of my code (I believe!) are:

In my searchview xml the input type is set to phone:

```
   <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="#5b74a8"
        android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:queryHint="Search"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:singleLine="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

In OnCreate I have :

```
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        // when the text in searchView changes, call the filter function
        adapter.filter(newText);
        return false;
    }
```

And my filter method, in another class, is :

```
    // Filter Class
    public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
//        _data is our list of Users, or contacts
        _data.clear();
//        If there is nothing in the searchbox,
//        then show all the contacts
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            _data.addAll(arraylist);
//            or else....
        } else {
            for (SelectUser wp : arraylist) {
//                If a contact's phone number matches the input thus far that the user
//                is filtering for, then include it in the listview.
                if (wp.getPhone().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                        .contains(charText)) {
                    _data.add(wp);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Can post more code if necessary.

Comment: see `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone#CONTENT_FILTER_URI`

Comment: @pskink Yes, I was reading over that one, couldn't find any solid to get my claws into. Anything else?