# Retrieving the contact details of phonebook in android

Tags: android, numbers, contacts

I am making an app to upload the phonebook of an android device on server side.
I am able to get the names in the phonebook but I am not getting the contact numbers of respective names.

I am using `People.NUMBER` method for getting the no of a contact.

Answer (score 0):

check these links:

[How to call Android contacts list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866769/how-to-call-android-contacts-list)

[How to get contacts from native phonebook in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253029/how-to-get-contacts-from-native-phonebook-in-android)

[How to obtain all details of a contact in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205246/how-to-obtain-all-details-of-a-contact-in-android)

[How to get the first name and last name from Android contacts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301064/how-to-get-the-firstname-and-lastname-from-android-contacts)

[How to import contacts from phonebook to our application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662473/how-to-import-contacts-from-phonebook-to-our-application)

[Android contacts extraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588378/android-contacts-extraction)

[How to get all android contacts but without those which are on SIM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338563/how-to-get-all-android-contacts-but-without-those-which-are-on-sim)

Answer (score 0):

use this code. this code stores the Contant name and number in the Arralist.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> contactData=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
         Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null);
         while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
             try{
             String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID)); 
             String name=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
             String hasPhone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)); 
             if (Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                 Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ contactId, null, null);
                 while (phones.moveToNext()) { 
                     String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                     HashMap<String,String> map=new HashMap<String,String>();
                     map.put("name", name);
                     map.put("number", phoneNumber);
                     contactData.add(map);
                 } 
                 phones.close(); 
             }
         }catch(Exception e){}
         }
```

Use the **contactData** list as you need.