# How to display Contacts in alphabetic order in Listview

Tags: android, alphabetical

I have a custom List view and i need to display the contacts in Alphabetical order can u provide the sample code how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 41):

you can get contacts in alphabatical order like this:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
```

refer these links for more cearity:

[How to call Android contacts list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866769/how-to-call-android-contacts-list)

[How to get contacts from native phonebook in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253029/how-to-get-contacts-from-native-phonebook-in-android)

[How to obtain all details of a contact in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205246/how-to-obtain-all-details-of-a-contact-in-android)

[How to get the first name and last name from Android contacts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301064/how-to-get-the-firstname-and-lastname-from-android-contacts)

[How to import contacts from phonebook to our application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662473/how-to-import-contacts-from-phonebook-to-our-application)

[Android contacts extraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588378/android-contacts-extraction)

[How to get all android contacts but without those which are on SIM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338563/how-to-get-all-android-contacts-but-without-those-which-are-on-sim)

For list you can refer this tutorial:

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to do this:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
```

Comment: Thanks. I wonder why the question owner didn't accept it

Answer (score 0):

use this code to retrieve the contacts

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> contactData=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
     Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null);
     while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
         try{
         String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID)); 
         String name=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
         String hasPhone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)); 
         if (Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
             Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ contactId, null, null);
             while (phones.moveToNext()) { 
                 String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                 HashMap<String,String> map=new HashMap<String,String>();
                 map.put("name", name);
                 map.put("number", phoneNumber);
                 contactData.add(map);
             } 
             phones.close(); 
         }
     }catch(Exception e){}
     }
```

Now the contact details are stored in the **contactData**  ArrayList. Now sort this arrayList like bellow

```
Collections.sort(contactData, new Comparator(){
                @Override
                public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
                    HashMap map1=(HashMap)o1;
                    HashMap map2=(HashMap)o2;
                    String s1=(String)map1.get("name");
                    String s2=(String)map2.get("name");
                    return s1.compareTo(s2);
                }
            });
```

Now the contact details are stored in the sorting order in the **contactData** ArrayList.

Comment: This worked , but there are duplicates in each contact

Answer (score 0):

I have added Alphabetic headers to contact list

```
new ReadContactTask(context, showProgressDialog,new OnContactReadListener() {
            @Override
            public void onContactRead(List<ContactItem> dummyList) {

                ArrayList<ContactItem> latestPhoneContacts = new ArrayList<>();

                if(dummyList!=null && dummyList.size()>0)
                {
                    tvNoResult.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    for(ContactItem contactItem : dummyList){
                        String contactNameInCapital = "";
                        if(contactItem.getContactName()!=null && contactItem.getContactName().length()>2){
                            contactNameInCapital = contactItem.getContactName().substring(0,1).toUpperCase();

                            if(contactNameInCapital.charAt(0) != previousContact.charAt(0))
                            {
                                latestPhoneContacts.add(new ContactItem(contactNameInCapital.substring(0,1)));
                                latestPhoneContacts.add(contactItem);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                latestPhoneContacts.add(contactItem);
                            }

                            previousContact = contactNameInCapital;
                        }
                    }
                    if(latestPhoneContacts!=null && latestPhoneContacts.size()>0)
                        contactListAdapter.addItems(latestPhoneContacts);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onContactEmpty() {

            }
        }).execute();
```

where

```
private String previousContact ="Zee";
```

Comment: what is ContactItem