# how to get phone number from my Contacts on android programing

Tags: java, android

i have EditText and button on my form.

how to do this:

when i press the button i want to open all my Contacts,

and when i pick one - i what that his phone number will be in the EditText

thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866769/how-to-call-android-contacts-list

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253029/how-to-get-contacts-from-native-phonebook-in-android

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205246/how-to-obtain-all-details-of-a-contact-in-android

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301064/how-to-get-the-firstname-and-lastname-from-android-contacts

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662473/how-to-import-contacts-from-phonebook-to-our-application

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588378/android-contacts-extraction

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338563/

Answer (score 1):

use this links May be it's useful for you.

http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/Contact/spelldial/org/ravelin/android/ContactAccessor.java.htm

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ContactManager/index.html

http://code.google.com/p/android-business-card/source/browse/trunk/android-business-card/BusinessCard/src/com/example/android/?r=3#android%2Fbusinesscard

Answer (score 0):

In this post you can read contact list.
[How to call Android contacts list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866769/how-to-call-android-contacts-list)
there are some methods...

Then set EditText with contact list content

*void    **setText**(CharSequence text, TextView.BufferType type)
Sets the text that this TextView is to display (see setText(CharSequence)) and also sets whether it is stored in a styleable/spannable buffer and whether it is editable.*

:-)