# Fetching contacts in android

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-contentprovider

I have inserted few contacts in through the android emulator.

I wanted to fetch the names, number,emails,etc. for each contact.

I understood that for fetching contact number we need to refer to

```
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI
```

instead of

```
ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI
```

My question is how do i link both the query results so that i can aggregate a single contact and its attributes together ? It seems that only ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME is common in both the results and the only attribute which can fetched in both the URI's without specifying in the query's projection.

Can anyone guide me ?

Thanks,
Adithya.

Answer (score 2):

try these links:

[How to call Android contacts list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866769/how-to-call-android-contacts-list)

[How to get contacts from native phonebook in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253029/how-to-get-contacts-from-native-phonebook-in-android)

[How to obtain all details of a contact in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205246/how-to-obtain-all-details-of-a-contact-in-android)

[How to get the first name and last name from Android contacts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301064/how-to-get-the-firstname-and-lastname-from-android-contacts)

[How to import contacts from phonebook to our application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662473/how-to-import-contacts-from-phonebook-to-our-application)

[Android contacts extraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588378/android-contacts-extraction)

[How to get all android contacts but without those which are on SIM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338563/how-to-get-all-android-contacts-but-without-those-which-are-on-sim)

Comment: can you tell me one thing ? If we can fetch all these in one query as it can be done in the third specified link then why do we have different URI's for each of the following :
1)ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone
2)ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email
 etc.. ?

Answer (score 0):

Use select from `ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI` and group results by `LOOKUP_KEY`. You'll receive a single cursor with phones, emails, etc., grouped by contact.

Answer (score 0):

In onactivityresult we r getting cursor to the contact database to access various fields of contact database we have ContactsContract.PhoneLookup through which we can get index various db columns and then acccess them.